# The "CreateAndroidManifestFile" task failed unexpectedly. System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready

Tags: firemonkey

I'm using D12. I have multiple Firemonkey projects. Trying to build one particular project and I only get this error from this project, none of the others. I have deleted androidmanifest.template and it gets rebuilt normally. It is identical to those created by other projects. ALL the other projects under both Android32 and 64 create the Androidmanifest.xml successfully and deploy. I'm driving myself nuts!! I can't believe I'm the only person to run into this. HELP!!!

I've tried everything I can think of. Deleted all androidmanifest related files in the project root. Replaced the manifest template from another project (which successfully builds in that project). I have copied the entire project to a new directory; same error. I've gone back to D11.3, same error.